# How to validate images and videos in NodeJS?

Tags: node.js, image, video

I'm writing a video/image upload service for my app. I allow uploading any video and image types. On the backend side, I need to validate (also distinguish) if the file is a valid video/image. Is there a unified tool/way to do this? Otherwise, I need to use multiple tools like `ffprobe`, `mmmagic` and/or `ImageMagick` separately.

Comment: what is the kind of validation you need, can you make the question more details?

Comment: I need to validate if it's indeed an image/video file. So it's not a text file, executable, or anything else. Previously I've done image validation by loading the file into ImageMagick or GD, if it failed, it's not an image. Now I need to do the same for videos as well, and I'm looking for a single tool to validate it.

Comment: I recommend you using this lib: https://github.com/sindresorhus/file-type